# Pasar imagen de firebase con picasso de una actividad a otra

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso

Estoy haciendo una app con Android Studio que se trata de una biblioteca online donde los usuarios pueden elegir y alquilar sus libros. Los datos los almaceno en firebase realtime y las imágenes en storage. En la lista principal (ListaActivity) todo va bien y carga los datos e imágenes sin problemas, el problema está cuando intento pasar a otra actividad (DetallesLibros) alguna imagen usando el put extra. Les dejo aquí mi código.

Edit: Ya lo he solucionado y además he conseguido que cuando se pulse en la imagen de la portada del libro de la lista, me lleve a otra actividad ampliando la imagen a pantalla completa. Dejo el código aquí, por si a alguien le viene bien.

```java
public class ListaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lista;
    FirebaseListAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    ImageView portada;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

        leerDatosFirebase();
    }

    private void leerDatosFirebase() {
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Libros");

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Libros");
        lista = findViewById(R.id.lvLista);
        FirebaseListOptions<Libros> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Libros>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.libros)
                .setQuery(query, Libros.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Object model, int position) {
                TextView titulo = v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
                TextView editorial = v.findViewById(R.id.tvEditorial);
                TextView autor = v.findViewById(R.id.tvAutor);
                TextView paginas = v.findViewById(R.id.tvPaginas);
                TextView isbn = v.findViewById(R.id.tvISBN);
                portada = v.findViewById(R.id.ivImagenDetalles);
                TextView resumen = v.findViewById(R.id.tvresumen);

                final Libros libros = (Libros) model;
                titulo.setText(libros.getTitulo());
                editorial.setText("Editorial: "+libros.getEditorial());
                autor.setText("Autor: "+libros.getAutor());
                paginas.setText("Páginas: "+libros.getPaginas());
                isbn.setText("ISBN: "+libros.getIsbn());
                Picasso.with(ListaActivity.this).load((libros.getPortada())).into(portada);
                resumen.setText(libros.getResumen());

                portada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent visorImagen = new Intent(v.getContext(), VisorImagen.class);
                        visorImagen.putExtra("POR", libros.getPortada());
                        startActivity(visorImagen);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent visorDetallesLibros = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetallesLibros.class);
                Libros libros = (Libros) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                visorDetallesLibros.putExtra("IMG", libros.getPortada());
                visorDetallesLibros.putExtra("TIT", libros.getTitulo());
                visorDetallesLibros.putExtra("DET", libros.getResumen());
                startActivity(visorDetallesLibros);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.opciones,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.miCuenta:
                startActivity(new Intent(ListaActivity.this,MiCuentaActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.miAbout:
                startActivity(new Intent(ListaActivity.this,AcercaDe.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.miSalir:
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del método `onCreate()` de tu Activity VisorImagen recibe el valor de esta forma:

```
Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 if(parametros !=null){
    String urlImagen = parametros.getString("POR"); 
 }
```

Comment: Si ya conseguí pasar la imagen, el problema ahora es que cuando pulso en un item de la lista, me lleva a otra activity donde me muestra la imagen, titulo y resumen del libro y además un boton que al pulsarlo me añadiría esos datos concretos (osea ese libro) a otra lista de otra activity y la verdad no sé aún como hacerlo.

Comment: Es decir, me falta la parte en la que se agregan esos datos a la otra activity, lo demás ya lo tengo hecho.